# How to create a random one-hot encoded pandas row?

Tags: python, pandas

How can add to a pandas dataframe a randomly one hot encoded pandas values?

For example, given three new columns, I would like to uniformly randomly assign a True value in one of the rows and False in the others. So far I tried the following:

```
np.random.seed(0)
batch['A'] = np.random.choice([True, False], df.shape[0])
batch['B'] = np.random.choice([True, False], df.shape[0])
batch['C'] = np.random.choice([True, False], df.shape[0])
```

However, this approach doesnt give me a one hot encoded version (in three rows only one can be true), any idea of how to create this columns properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

```
choices = np.random.choice(3, df.shape[0])
batch['A'] = choices == 0
batch['B'] = choices == 1
batch['C'] = choices == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

First, set all entries to `False`

Then, for each row:

```
col_choice = random.choice(df.columns)
batch[col_choice] = True
```

I trust that you can vectorize this on your own ...

Answer (score 1):

Something like `str.get_dummies`

```
df['new'] = np.random.choice(list('ABC'), df.shape[0])
df.new.str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=list('ABC'),fill_value=0)
Out[316]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  0  1
1  1  0  0
2  0  0  1
```